# how to allow user's input even if you don't know how many will input

Tags: java

I am now going to make a program that can allow user's to enter their ID number.
But I don't know how to do because I don't know how many ID number user's will input.
For example:
If I know user's wanna put 2 person's ID number, so my code will be like this:

```
//get 2 people's student ID
          System.out.print("Enter the first people's student ID: ");
          String ID1 = input.next();
          System.out.print("Enter the second people's student ID: ");
          String ID2 = input.next();
```

If I know user's wanna put 3 person's ID number, so my code will be like this:

```
//get 3 people's student ID
              System.out.print("Enter the first people's student ID: ");
              String ID1 = input.next();
              System.out.print("Enter the second people's student ID: ");
              String ID2 = input.next();
              System.out.print("Enter the third people's student ID: ");
              String ID3 = input.next();
```

But this is the case that I know how many number that user will enter.  If I don't know how many number will they enter, What can I do to allow user's input and store the number they enter?

Comment: Maybe try a loop?

Comment: Prompt user how many IDs they have, loop over and prompt then put data from user in array...

Comment: @AndrewLi Probably ArrayList<> more specifically since he says he doesn't know the limit ;)

Comment: @jonk Well, it's already known how many things are going to be in the array, but if they want to expand, yes an ArrayList would be appropriate

Comment: @AndrewLi ah you modified slightly to include prompting for the limit, that's fair.

Comment: Yes! I know it needs loop and I am going to learn something about array! Thank you two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming problem, this is a design problem. You have to design your program such that either the user would be able to signal the end of input, or you should keep going forever with the same loop.

The user might use special `EOF` character to signal end of input. This character is basically a `CTRL-D`. Or if the user input is given from a file, when file ends an `EOF` is automatically sent to your program.

Or you can check a special user ID that indicates end of input (such as -1). Or you can ask the number of ids first. Or your program might exit after a single id and user might restart it. It all depends on your design.

In either case you should build a loop so that you program can handle any number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
List<String> ids= new ArrayList<>();
while (true){
    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
    String val = input.next();
    if ( val.equals("done") )
            break;
    ids.add( val );
}
```

Comment: This is a great way! But I haven't learnt array yet. I will go to learn it right now!